# Сравнение значений в GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем, привет, можете помочь пожалуйста - у меня есть код который делает неполное сравнение двух списков.
Я хочу чтобы сравнение выполнялось после открытия файла через GUI. Я так понимаю, мне нужно обернуть сравнение в функцию и вывести в GUI, но не знаю как это сделать.
Заранее спасибо

```
import fileinput
from re import search
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

root = Tk()
root.title("DNS search")
root.minsize(width=300,height=300)

txt = Text(root, width=40, height=15,font="14")
txt.pack()

op = askopenfilename()

for i in fileinput.input(op):
    txt.insert(END,i)

def _save():
    sa = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".espace", filetypes=(("Excel", "*.csv"),("All Files", "*.*"),("Text","*.txt")))
    content = txt.get(1.0, END)
    f = open(sa, "w")
    f.write(content)
    f.close()

m = Menu(root)
root.config (menu=m)
fm = Menu (m)
m.add_command(label= "Save", command=_save)


f1 = open("C:\dns\1.txt")
f2 = open("C:\dns\dns.txt")
f3 = open("export251.txt", 'w')
pat = f2.read().replace('\n', '|')
for i in f1.readline():
    if search(pat, i):
        f3.write(i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавляете кнопку открытия первого файла, кнопку открытия второго файла и кнопку сравнения. В обработчике нажатия кнопки сравнения выполняете сравнение.